# Why does Python tell me to sort before taking a random sample?

Tags: python, sorting, random

Python just gave me weird advice:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample({1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    random.sample({1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}, 2)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\random.py", line 466, in sample
    raise TypeError("Population must be a sequence.  For dicts or sets, use sorted(d).")
TypeError: Population must be a sequence.  For dicts or sets, use sorted(d).
```

Note the second part of the last error line. Why should I sort if I'm going to randomize a moment later anyway? Seems like wasting O(n log n) time.

Comment: It's erroring because iter('foo') is an iterator, not a sequence.  What version are you on?  I get "For dicts, use list(d).")" .. basically, 'find some way to turn it into a list'..

Comment: I suppose you might use sorted to get reliable repeatable results.

Comment: @JeffUK I replaced it with a dict example. But that's irrelevant, as I'm not asking why I got an error.

Comment: You get the error because it's not a sequence.  You need to find some way to make it a sequence.  sorted(d) is one way.  you could also use list(d).

Comment: @JeffUK I never asked why I got the error. I asked, both in title and body, why I should sort. That's the question, nothing else.

Comment: @nocomment you don't have to sort.. the message is not correct. Try either sorting or not sorting both work!

Comment: @JeffUK Yes, most of the time, both work. So it's weird that Python tells me to do it inefficiently. And sometimes, sorting even *doesn't* work (if the dict keys don't support comparisons).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the commit history of cpython - My emphasis: [github](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/4fe002045fcf40823154b709fef0948b2bc5e934)

> In the future, the *population* must be a sequence.  Instances of
> :class:`set` are no longer supported.  The set must first be converted
> to a :class:`list` or :class:`tuple`, ***preferably*** in a
> deterministic   order so that the sample is reproducible.

If you don't care about reproducibility sorting is not necessary.

Comment: That makes sense. I'd say it would be good if the error message said *"For dicts or sets, use list(d), or sorted(d) for reproducibility"*.

Comment: Note that this is also explained in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) : Deprecated since version 3.9: In the future, the population must be a sequence. Instances of set are no longer supported. The set must first be converted to a list or tuple, preferably in a deterministic order so that the sample is reproducible.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I think that commit is probably from the documentation change.  I just looked there first to see when it was introduced!